# Download binaries for SUN LDAP SDK for C To run on windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ldap

I want to find binaries for the SUN LDAP SDK for C to run on Windows 7 on a VS 2010 professional edition. BUT I have been unable to do so. 
Please help me find binaries that run.

Comment: What did your Oracle Support Representative say? Have you purchased the requisite Oracle Legacy Sun LDAP SDK Support contract? You need at least the Oracle Standard Edition Support edition of the Oracle Legacy Sun LDAP SDK Support contract before you can even *see* the link to download the file in the management portal. But you need the Oracle Enterprise Edition Support edition to download it.

Answer (score 0):

I typed [`SUN LDAP SDK for C` into Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=SUN+LDAP+SDK+for+C) and looked at the [first result](https://oss.oracle.com/projects/sun-ldapcsdk/):

> Some releases of Oracle products contain Sun LDAP C SDK source and library files and include them in product distributions.
>
> PeopleSoft PeopleTools includes the Sun LDAP C SDK source files without modifications. We make the source code of the original components (covered under the terms of the MPL license) available here to the Open Source Community. Please note that PeopleTools releases moving forward from 8.52 onward will no longer use or distribute the Sun LDAP C SDK source files.
>
> The LDAP libraries containing both source and object files for all supported platforms are available in "zip" archive format from this project's "Downloads" link. The zip archives available for download include:
>
> ...
>
> [sun_ldap_c_sdk_for_psft.zip](http://oss.oracle.com/projects/sun-ldapcsdk/dist/files/sun_ldap_c_sdk_for_psft.zip)

**EDIT** It seems that you do not understand that you can use the `sun_ldap_c_sdk_for_psft.zip` files without it including a `.lib` file. I would recommend reading [Using Run-Time Dynamic Linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686944(v=vs.85).aspx) and [How To Create 32-bit Import Libraries Without .OBJs or Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313) (you can roll-your-own "unofficial" `.lib`).

Comment: i have seen this before. THere are no .lib files

Comment: You don't need lib files to use a library.

Comment: If you are precious about the `lib` files you can use the Mozilla LDAP C SDK which, after doing some more [research](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mozilla+ldap+sdk+sun+ldap+sdk), is a newer version of the Sun LDAP SDK. http://www-archive.mozilla.org/directory/csdk-docs/getstart.htm#library_supply

Comment: Please do your "research" more. I have seen that doc before. But nowhere does it provide you the built binaries for the LDAP SDK. I want the binaries with the .lib files

Comment: Man! You have wasted my time. Currently, mozilla has not pre build binaries for LDAP C SDK on windows. YOu need to build their source yourself. Do you know how to do that

Comment: You download it and build it. Research the instructions: http://www-archive.mozilla.org/directory/csdk.html